# How do you make CSS rotate dynamic?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamicaly change the rotation angle of my two h1 elements to match the angle of the black line in the center of the page as the page shrinks and grows. How would I go about calculating this in CSS? Below you will find my HTML and CSS code. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.main-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 90vw;
}

.logo {
  height: 30px;
}

.main-nav {
  min-width: 20rem;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.hero {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}

.triangle {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 100%);
}

.skyler-kroll__text {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  /*This is what I need to dynamically calculate.*/
  rotate: -40deg;
  top: 45%;
  left: 35.5%;
  animation: moveInLeft 1s ease-out;
}

.web-developer__text {
  /* color: rgb(218, 41, 41); */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #38d39f, #38a4d3);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  rotate: calc(-40deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 250px;
  animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.styles.css">
  <title>Skyler Kroll | Web Developer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main-head">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img class="logo" src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="main-content">
    <header class="hero">
      <div class="triangle">
        <h1 class="skyler-kroll__text">Skyler Kroll</h1>
      </div>
      <h1 class="web-developer__text">Web Developer</h1>
    </header>
  </main>
</body>
```

[image: Portfolio Hero]

Comment: Use a custom property `--angle` (without 'deg' unit) and do your calculations on that variable with CSS and/or JS. Convert the result to 'deg' unit like `--result: calc(var(--angle) * 1deg)`. Assign the result to your headers using `transform: rotate(var(--result));`

Comment: Rotating the two headers along the hypotenuse would involve trig math and may get too complicated for just two lines of text: they need to pivot around the same point on the hypotenuse, taking their `transform-origin` into account (one above, one below the pivot point), possible margin/padding offset. Provided they are centered on the hypotenuse, otherwise you need to account for left/right shift. It would make more sense to me to simply add the text to the background image with Photoshop and rotate the image with a variable in `transform: rotate(...deg);`. Does this make any sense?

Comment: It can be done fully variable in CSS for sure, check this [Codepen: Text Styles Challenge](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/yLoEbgN?editors=0100) I created a few months ago showcasing the *price tag ribbons* on the cards, but it seems a bit overkill in your case. Check the CSS for *2. Trigonometry in CSS* and *4. CSS only ribbon mechanism*, especially the `--angle` definition and modification. *Warning*, not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: Hello Rene, I tried the first method and that produces the same static angle as before. As far as maths go, I'm not very well versed and don't know trig. I would try taking a screenshot and adding the text, then setting said screenshot as the background, but I have animations I'd like to keep.

Would this be easier to solve with JS?

Comment: If you need to have the triangle from corner to corner there is no avoiding the use of trigonometry as it changes upon browser resize. I'd opt for JS as you need the current `width` and `height` of the *parent container* to calculate the current angle of the slanted side (*hypotenuse*). Once you calculated the angle you can apply it to some CSS variable to adjust the angle of both lines of text. I'm no math-pro either so to solve this I'd read [MathsIsFun: Finding an Angle...](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-angle-right-triangle.html) as it explains exactly what you need...